# pygame.error: video system not initialized (Alien Invasion)

Tags: pygame

I'm currently following a python tutorial on a book and have finally coming to creating a pygame.
After manually typing each code,

The Game (Alien Invasion)

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    ship = Ship(screen)

bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()

    pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

Settings:

```
class Settings():

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

Ship:

```
import pygame

class Ship():

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

I keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ff/Desktop/alien invasion/alien_invasion.py", line 21, in <module>
    for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

I've made sure each line and indentation is properly inserted. 
Does anyone know how to fix this?

-----edit-----

The pygame initialization error is fixed after I moved `pygame.init()` outside the while loop, but now it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ff/Desktop/alien invasion/alien_invasion.py", line 27, in <module>
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
NameError: name 'screen' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `run_game()` is called after your while loop so your pygame modules have not been initialized before you start looking for events. Try moving it before the while loop.

Edit: If you want to access `screen`, `ai_settings`, and `ship` outside of your function `run_game()` then you will need to edit your code like this:

```
def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    ship = Ship(screen)

    return screen, ai_settings, ship

bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

screen, ai_settings, ship = run_game()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Notable parts are the lines

```
    return screen, ai_settings, ship
```

and

```
screen, ai_settings, ship = run_game()
```

Comment: Ok, that error is gone but now it says `NameError: name 'screen' is not defined`. I'm pretty sure `screen` is defined, `class Settings():

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen.height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)`

Comment: @frankfu88 Screen only exists within the scope of your function `run_game()`. In order to use it in your while loop you will need to return it.

Comment: @frankfu88 Upon further inspection, did you mean for your while statement to be indented so that it is inside `run_game()`? It would solve your problems if it was.

Comment: No, I meant every line is following the correct format, so I assume there shouldn't be a prb. I moved 'pygame.init' before the while loop and the pygame error is gone. What do you mean by I need to return the loop?

Comment: @frankfu88 Sorry, I meant return screen from `run_game()`. So something like `return screen` at the end of your `run_game()`. I ask about indentation because `screen`, `ai_settings`, and `ship` all only exist within `run_game()` currently and you try to access them in your while loop. If you want to keep the while loop outside your function then you will need to return all three of these from `run_game()`, like `return screen, ai_settings, ship`. Then, before your while loop have `screen, ai_settings, ship = run_game()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked :) Upon running the code, my python icon keeps 'jumping' and doesn't launch the the game?

Comment: @frankfu88 I don't have any problems when running it. I'm running it with Python 3.7.6 and pygame 1.9.6 on Windows 10 in Pycharm 2019.3.3.